# CloudFront Path Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to trigger a Lambda function from CloudFront when a Viewer Request event occurs, for the following cases:

- any URL of directory or subdirectory
- any *.html or *.htm file inside one of this subdirectory

I am trying to figure out the best way to create behaviours.
So far, I have 2 behaviours

- */      for root / any subdirectorys
- *.html*  for htm and html files

I don't know if there is a way to have only one Path for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several options, I came to the conclusion that using two different behaviours is the only working option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .html for html and htm files. Because in URL directory serve like

```
https://www.example.com/about/
```

actually it serve

```
https://www.example.com/about/index.html
```

It will trigger if you do it for .html

Comment: This behaviour is not the case for Amazon CloudFront by default. With just *.html as Path, it does not trigger the lambda function